# Different memory address of same variable

Tags: c++, memory-management

Why is the address of two `k` different as shown in output of following code?

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int anu[1000000];
int calc(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
    long long int k;
    k=(long long int)a*d*d+b*d+c;
    return k%1000000;
}
int main()
{
    int t,n,i,a,b,c,d,k;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {   
        scanf("%d %d %d %d %d",&n,&a,&b,&c,&d);
        memset(anu,0,sizeof(int)*1000000);
        anu[d]=1;
        vector<int> anu1;
        anu1.push_back(d);
        for(i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            k=calc(a,b,c,anu1[i-1]);
            anu1.push_back(k);
            anu[k]=anu[k]?0:1;
        }
        d=0;k=0;
        printf("address of k=%d ",&k);
        for(i=0;i<1000000;i++)
        {
            if(anu[i])
                {
                if(d%2)
                k-=i;
                else
                k+=i;
                d++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d address of final k=%d\n",abs(k),&k);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:
1 1 1 1 1 1

Output:
Address of k=-1074414672 0 address of final k=1072693248

Comment: Looks like the result of aggressive optimization.

Comment: Are you on a 32 or 64 bit system?

Comment: `"address of k=%d ",&k` and have you confirmed that sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*)? If not, then that printf() isn't going to work as you think it will. Why not use typesafe output such as cout, or even inspect the address in a debugger, instead of relying on mistake-prone printf()?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie even if the size is different, the results would be consistent if the address is the same. (Though if the results are the same, that wouldn't be enough to say the address was the same with that issue.)

Comment: you have lots of formatting errors, see here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b37fb510885d4c9c

Comment: When run in Visual Studio, it only complains for the use of scanf (suggesting use of scanf_s instead) but the same address is printed every time

Comment: Solving code chefs team split ... :)

Comment: @Jaswant Singh Ranawat -- next time, use cout to inspect values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I build with clang++ (with as many warnings enabled as I could) I get these warnings:

```
k.cpp:45:45: error: call to 'abs' is ambiguous
        printf("%d address of final k=%d\n",abs(k),&k);
                                            ^~~
/usr/local/include/c++/v1/cmath:660:1: note: candidate function
abs(float __x) _NOEXCEPT {return fabsf(__x);}
^
/usr/local/include/c++/v1/cmath:664:1: note: candidate function
abs(double __x) _NOEXCEPT {return fabs(__x);}
^
/usr/local/include/c++/v1/cmath:668:1: note: candidate function
abs(long double __x) _NOEXCEPT {return fabsl(__x);}
^
```

This is because you don't include `<cstdlib>` which declares the integer version of `abs`. Without that include the compiler have to guess which function it should use, and it seems it chooses poorly as it picks one of the floating point variants from `<cmath>`. This leads to you overwriting the next argument in `printf` call.

When building a program, I advise everyone to enable as many warnings as possible, they usually point out things like undefined behavior as in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Without taking the address of the `k` variable, the compiler is allowed to use *registers* to hold the value of `k`.

With most processors, registers do not have a physical address.  They are not in the CPU address space.

By printing the address of the `k` variable, you are telling the compiler to either store the variable in memory or for the compiler to generate an address.

Not all variables need to be stored in addressable memory; they can be store in registers.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should print pointers with `%p`
2. `abs()` returns floating point number, casting it to int before printing solves the problem

The line would be correct with:

```
printf("%d address of final k=%d\n",(int)abs(k),&k);
```